# How to insert a variable of message in specific column in specific line

Tags: bash, awk, vim, sed, echo

I want to insert a Hash messages in my txt file in linux based environment. for example i have one file (ABCD.sh)
it has 100 of lines that program,
i want to add comment message 60th line in 80th column number (#ADDED TEST).

```
 58:######################################################################
 59:SRC ==                                                              
 60:SRC ==                                                    #ADDED TEST
 61:SRC ==
```

Comment: What if there's already text in the 80th column?

Comment: have to replace and insert

Comment: "replace" and "insert" are 2 opposite requirements - you can't do both at the same time. Do you want to push the existing chars (blanks presumably) 10 chars to the right so your line ends up 10 chars wider or replace them with `#ADDED TEXT` so your line ends up the same length as it was before. I'm assuming your lines ARE at least 80 chars wide already.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

`awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} FNR==60{$80="your_text"} 1'  Input_file`

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Give it sometime and you coild select any answer out of all as correct one too.

Comment: How can that be working? There's only 1 `:` in the input and the script is trying to add text after the 79th `:`.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sorry sir, I thought delimiter is `:` so I have posted it.

Comment: I understand that, I just don't understand how the OP can say its working!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E '60s/./ADDED TEXT/80' file
```